# how can i loop through dynamic ObservableCollection class inside method

Tags: c#, wpf

**hi,**
I'm trying to pass dynamic [**ObservableCollection**] List to method
how can i get keys and loop through values from inside method **without** passing the Class [**Player**]

this my code

```
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Player> items = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    public TEST()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GroupsDataG.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add Random Data On Click
        items.Add(new Player() { ID = 1, FName = "aaaa", LName = "bbbb" });
        items.Add(new Player() { ID = 2, FName = "cccc", LName = "yyyyy" });

        // Passing The [ObservableCollection] List to a method
        GetMyData(items);
    }

    public static void GetMyData<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        // How Can i get values
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is. Do you need `GetMyData(ObservableCollection<Player> collection)` instead of `GetMyData<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)`?

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that has common properties/methods you wish to access "generically" and then use that in your GetMyData method. GetMyData may then access anything defined in this interface regardless of what class T is as long as it implements the interface:

```
public interface IPlayer
{
    int ID { get; }
    string FName { get; set; }
    string LName { get; set; }
}

public class Player : IPlayer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherPlayer : IPlayer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}

//you can also change the parameter from ObservableCollection to IEnumerable if all you need is to iterate through a collection. this allows the method to accept different types of generic collections and not just ObservableCollection.
public static void GetMyData<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IPlayer
{
    // How Can i get values
    foreach (T player in collection)
    {
        //now you can access IPlayer
        player.ID = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: without generic constraint `player.ID` won't compile, because type T doesn't have ID property/field. T can very well be just `object`